# В чем разница между valueOf и toString

Tags: javascript

В чем разница между ними?
И то, и то выводит нам строку, которую мы указывает в `return`, при том `valueOf`, если явно указано, затирает `toString`.
Почитал пару источников, но так и не понял разницы. Если можно, поподробнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: разница в том **когда** вызываются эти функции, а что за `stringOf`? может быть `toString`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Рискну предположить что Вы имеете ввиду функции `valueOf` и `toString`.
Разница между ними чуть размыта, но понятна:

- `valueOf` используется для численного преобразования объекта (`foo + 42`, `++bar`, etc.). Но есть он далеко не у всех объектов (т. е. есть, но возвращает сам объект, поэтому игнорируется) и **обязан** возвращать примитив, иначе будет проигнорирован и будет вызван `toString`.
- `toString` используется для строкового преобразования объекта (`alert(foo)`). Есть у всех объектов, обычно не очень информативен (`[object Object]`), но очень удобен, если нужно перегрузить оператор, например (в `JS` нет перегрузки/создания операторов). Тоже обязан вернуть примитив.

Читать [подробнее](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-conversion).
У использования этих операторов есть нюансы (как везде в `JS`, наверное, экой коварный язык однако!), которые проще узнать из спецификации.

- [www.ecma-international.org](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)
- [whatwg.org](https://whatwg.org/specs/)
- [ES5 на русском](http://es5.javascript.ru/)
- [Отличный учебник `JS`](https://learn.javascript.ru/)

Comment: наверно я поэтому сильно разницы не уловил, т.к и то и то возвращает примитив, просто в return я не могу прописать foo  + 42 и там и там? в случае если foo строка то сконкатенирует и виведет одно и тоже что в случае с valueOf, что в случае с toString?

Comment: @ArtemPalamarchuk, проще, наверное, понять смысл методов: `value` - значение, `string` - строка. Т. е. при операциях нужно как бы именно значение, а где нужно начертать объект текстом - используем строку. `foo + 42` -> `valueOf`; `alert(foo)` -> `toString`.

Comment: я понял, хорошо, спасибо

Answer (score 9):

Если непонятно в источниках, стоит обратиться к [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toprimitive):
какой из данных методах будет вызван определяется внутри абстрактной операции `ToPrimitive`, которая выполняется практически при всех операциях с объектами, например: арифметические операции, операции сравнения и т.д.

Операция `ToPrimitive ( input [, PreferredType] )`

Когда *Type(input)* - *Object*, выполняются следующие шаги:

1. Если *PreferredType* отсутствует, *hint* будет *"default"*.
2. Если *PreferredType* подсказывает *String*, *hint* будет *"string"*.
3. Если *PreferredType* подсказывает *Number*, *hint* будет *"number"*.
4. Пусть *exoticToPrim* - **GetMethod(input, @@toPrimitive)**.
5. Если *exoticToPrim* это не *undefined*, тогда

   1. *result* будет **Call(exoticToPrim, input, «hint»)**.
      ReturnIfAbrupt(result).
   2. Если **Type(result)** не *Object*, вернуть *result*.
   3. Бросить исключение *TypeError*.
6. Если *hint*=*"default"*, *hint* будет *"number"*.
7. Вернуть результат **OrdinaryToPrimitive(input,hint)**.

Как видно из алгоритма, если у объекта нет внутренней экзотической функции для приведения к примитивному значению будет вызываться *OrdinaryToPrimitive*.

При вызове абстрактной операции *OrdinaryToPrimitive* с аргументами *O* и *hint*, будут выполняться следующие шаги:

1. Проверка типа: **Type(O)** - *Object*
2. Проверка типа: **Type(hint)** это *String* и значение *"string"* или *"number"*.
3. Если *hint* = *"string"*, тогда

   1. *methodNames* будет списком *«"toString", "valueOf"»*.
4. Иначе,

   1. *methodNames* будет списком *«"valueOf", "toString"»*.
5. Для каждого *name* из *methodNames*

   1. *method* будет **Get(O, name)**.
   2. Если **IsCallable(method)** = *true*, тогда
   3. *result* = **Call(method, O)**.
   4. Если **Type(result)** не *Object*, вернуть *result*.
6. Бросить исключение *TypeError*.

**Примечание:** Когда *ToPrimitive* вызывается без параметра *hint*, поведение такое же, как в случае передачи *hint* значения *Number*. Однако, объекты могут переопределить это поведения определив метод *@@toPrimitive*. Из объектов в текущей спецификации только объекты *Date* и *Symbol* переопределяют поведение по умолчанию. Объекты *Date* рассматривает вызов без передачи *hint*, как будто передали *String*.

Comment: Безразмерно преклоняюсь перед спецификациями, но их сухой язык крайне малоинформативен. Если ты, конечно, не собираешь интерпретатор.

Comment: @Other, мне кажется это тот самый случай, когда можно один раз посмотреть алгоритм и понять как это действует, чем заучивать при каких типах и что будет вызываться

Comment: Быть может. Хотя изучение подобных алгоритмов, возможно, уместнее при создании интерпретатора, а не простой работы с языком. Но прочитал с удовольствием.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Немного не понял: "если у объекта нет внутренней экзотической функции", это про `@@toPrimitive`? Эту функцию нельзя самому объявить, сам язык только может?

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько, можно, для этого есть специальный Symbol: `Symbol.toPrimitive`