# Js, численное преобразование в объектах

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Изучаю Js и остановился на одном моменте не могу понять об численном преобразовании объектов. В главе пишет, что численное преобразование делается через метод `valueOf`, а если его нет — то `toString`. Тогда почему в примере ниже числа складываются как строки в `a + b`?

```
var a = {
  valueOf: function() {
    return "1";
  }
};
var b = {
  valueOf: function() {
    return "2";
  }
};

alert(a + b); // "12"
alert(a - b); // "1" - "2" = -1
```

Answer (score 5):

> *почему в примере ниже числа складываются как строки*

Потому, что методы valueOf в обоих случаях возвращают строки, а если хотя бы один из операндов оператора *+* строка, то и второй операнд так же будет приведен к строке.

Заменив возвращаемое значение на число, результат станет ожидаемым.

```js
var a = {
  valueOf: function() {
    return 1;
  }
};
var b = {
  valueOf: function() {
    return 2;
  }
};

console.log(a + b);
```

---

Если копнуть чуть глубже, можно найти в спецификации [алгоритм для оператора +](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

В котором можно отметить шаги 5,6,7, в которых объекты приводятся к примитивам, и если хотя бы один из объектов был приведен к строке, то дальше происходит сложение строк.

5. lprim <= *ToPrimitive(lval)*.
6. rprim <= *ToPrimitive(rval)*.
7. Если *Type(lprim)* или *Type(rprim)* - это строка, то

   1. lstr <= *ToString(lprim)*.
   2. rstr <= *ToString(rprim)*.
   3. Вернуть строку, которая является результатом конкатенации строк lstr и rstr.

Подробнее про *ToPrimitive* можно посмотреть в ответе на вопрос [В чем разница между valueOf и toString](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/544918/186999)