# Для чего используется плюс перед new Date и style.opacity?

Tags: javascript

Есть код на JS, аналогичный эффекту `fadeIn` в jQuery. Некоторые моменты я не могу понять.

1. `var last = +new Date();` - что здесь означает `+`? Для чего он?
2. `el.style.opacity = +el.style.opacity + (new Date() - last) / 400;` - аналогично и здесь: для чего нужен `+`?
3. `last = +new Date();` - здесь я тоже не могу понять назначение `+`
4. `if (+el.style.opacity < 1)` - а здесь тем более...

```js
function fadeIn(el) {
  el.style.opacity = 0;
  var last = +new Date();
  var tick = function() {
    el.style.opacity = +el.style.opacity + (new Date() - last) / 400;
    last = +new Date();
    if (+el.style.opacity < 1) {
      (window.requestAnimationFrame && requestAnimationFrame(tick)) || setTimeout(tick, 16);
    }
  };
  tick();
}

fadeIn(el);
```

Comment: Представление объекта в численном виде: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221539/what-does-the-plus-sign-do-in-new-date

Comment: А для `style.opacity` схожий принцип: `style.opacity` имеет тип `string`, а использование унарного `+` приводит `string` к `number`.

Comment: перед new Date - не зачем

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Согласно спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-unary-plus-operator)

> Оператор "Унарный **+**" преобразует свой операнд к типу Number.

#### Для чего это нужно в коде в вопросе?

`el.style.opacity` - возвращает строку, поэтому [при сложении ее с числом, это число было бы приведено к строке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/663301/186999) и произошла бы обычная конкатенация строк, например:

```
el.style.opacity = 1
el.style.opacity = el.style.opacity + 2
```

значением `el.style.opacity` в данном случае будет `"12"`, а не `3`.

---

При этом, в случае с `Date`, можно опустить этот оператор, так как аргументы "оператора **–**" и так будут приведены к числу. Но даже и этого не нужно, так как есть метод [`now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now), который уже возвращает число.

Кроме того вместо расчета *приращения* прозрачности можно просто заново рассчитывать полное значение прозрачности и вообще убрать приведение к числу и не хранить последнее значение timestamp.

Исходя из этого, код можно переписать так:

```js
function fadeIn(el) {
  el.style.opacity = 0;
  var start = Date.now();
  var tick = function() {
    el.style.opacity = (Date.now() - start) / 400;
    if (el.style.opacity < 1) {
      (window.requestAnimationFrame && requestAnimationFrame(tick)) || setTimeout(tick, 16);
    }
  };
  tick();
}

fadeIn(document.getElementById('a'));
```

```css
#a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
```

Так как callback для `requestAnimationFrame` первым параметром принимает текущий timestamp, который соответствует значению возвращаемому [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) можно использовать его например так:

```js
function fadeIn(el) {
  el.style.opacity = 0;
  var start = performance.now();
  var tick = function(timestamp) {
    el.style.opacity = (timestamp - start) / 400;
    if (el.style.opacity < 1) {
      (window.requestAnimationFrame && requestAnimationFrame(tick)) || setTimeout(tick, 16);
    }
  };
  tick();
}

fadeIn(document.getElementById('a'));
```

```css
#a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Плюс используется для преобразования к числовому типу.

"new Date()" (без плюса) - объект
typeof(new Date()) => "object"

"+new Date()" - число
typeof(+new Date()) => "number"

[Преобразование к числу, унарный плюс +](https://learn.javascript.ru/operators#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83-%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%81)

Answer (score 2):

`+` перед значением используется для преобразования в число. Например:

```js
var x = prompt("Введи число");
alert(typeof x);
```

Видно что x не является числом а строкой. Но стоит добавить + перед `prompt` как он скажет что наша переменная число.

```js
var x = +prompt("Введи число");
alert(typeof x);
```

Еще одно применение это сложение строки и строки/числа

```js
// не работает
alert("12"+"12")
//работает
alert(+"12"+12);
//работает
alert(+"12"+(+"12"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Для преобразования к числу в явном виде можно вызвать Number(val), либо, что короче, поставить перед выражением унарный плюс "+", почитать подробнее про преобразования типов в JS можно в [учебнике Кантора](https://learn.javascript.ru/types-conversion#%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)