# JS: существует таблица неявного приведения типов?

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование, типы

Привет!

Существует таблица неявного приведения типов или где правильные ответы смотреть?

Пример:

```
[1] + [2] - [3]
= 9
```

или:

```
{} + {}
= "[object Object][object Object]"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Правильные ответы есть в [спецификации](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/).

В примерах в вопросе нужно смотреть операции [сложения](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus-runtime-semantics-evaluation) и [вычитания](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-subtraction-operator-minus-runtime-semantics-evaluation).

---

Как видно из алгоритма, в случае сложения сначала операнды приводятся к примитивному типу, с помощью вызова внутренней функции [ToPrimitive](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-toprimitive) (алгоритм ToPrimivite можно также увидеть в ответе на вопрос [В чем разница между `valueOf` и `toString`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/544918/186999))

Далее, если хотя бы один из операндов строка - производится сложение строк.
В противном случае, операнды приводятся к числу и выполняется сложение чисел.

---

В случае с вычитанием - операнды *сразу* приводятся к числу.

Рассмотрим первый пример из вопроса: `[1] + [2] - [3]`

1. Происходит вычисление `[1] + [2]`.

   1. операнды приводятся к примитивному типу, для массивов - это равносильно вызову `ToString`, следовательно: `[1]+[2] -> "1"+"2"`
   2. складываются строки: `"1"+"2" = "12"`
2. Происходит вычисление `"12" - [3]`.

   1. Операнды приводятся к числам: `"12" -> 12`, `[3] -> "3" -> 3`
   2. вычитание: `12 - 3 = 9`

---