# Почему в JS результатом var elem = '2'+'2'-'2' будет 20?

Tags: javascript

при этом typeof (elem) будет number, а typeof ('2') будет string...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [JS: существует таблица неявного приведения типов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/750963/js-%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: Потому что сначала будет работать `'2' + '2'`, что дает `'22'`, а потом `'22' - 2`, по умолчанию при минусе операнды конвертируются в числа для минуса, вот и получается, что строка 22 уже не строка, а число, 22 - 2 = 20

Comment: Спасибо! я это и пытался выяснить!

Answer (score 3):

*Хорошо бы указать, какой результат бы Вас устроил.*

Потому что JavaScript умеет складывать строки, а вычитать строки - не умеет. Поэтому приходится вычитать числа.

Comment: Если бы не умел - то была бы ошибка. А тут - умеет, но странным образом)

Comment: @andreymal Сейчас ТС окончательно запутается.

Comment: @Igor а почему `parseInt(0.0000001) === 1`, не знаете случаем? :)

Comment: @InDevX Знаю. `0.0000001 = 1е-7`.

Comment: @Igor спасибо! Хотя тоже, где логика... По сути, это 1 умножается на 10^-7, т.е. на 0.00... Откуда 1 не понятно

Comment: @InDevX Как раз откуда единица - понятно. Число "одна десятимилионная" не существует во время выполнения кода как единица с цепочкой нулей перед ней. Оно (число) существует в каком-то внутреннем представлении. Функция `parseInt` принимает на вход строку. При переводе одной десятимиллионной в строку используется некая внутренняя логика, которая для таких маленьких чисел применяет экспоненциальный формат. В `parseInt`, таким образом, попадает строка `"1е-7"`, из которой в число преобразуется начальный кусок до первого символа, который не может быть преобразован.

Comment: Там не какая-то внутренняя логика, а указано в спецификации в пункте 8 и 9 здесь - https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-tostring-applied-to-the-number-type

Comment: @PavelGrishaev Очень хорошо.

Comment: @InDevX, вы еще не видели `parseInt(1 / 0, 19) === 18`

Comment: @Igor имел ввиду здравому смыслу не понятно. одна милионная это 0, но одна десяти-милионная вдруг стала единицей

Comment: Это же типичный Garbage in, garbage out. Вы вызываете функцию которая ожидает на входе строку с числом. На входе мусор, на выходе что угодно.