# Преобразование типов на примере [] == '0' которое вернет false

Tags: javascript

Правильно ли я понял преобразование типов? Я читал [это](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3).

Алгоритм:

`[]` приводится к примитиву потому что:

> If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String or Number,
>   return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.

[ToPrimitive](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1) вызывается <strike>с hint String</strike>, то есть подсказка что нужно преобразовать к строке. Такая подсказка указана из-за того что `'0'` строка.

`ToPrimitive` вызывает [`toString`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8), возвращается пустая строка `''` (перечисление элементов через запятую).

После этого выполняется еще одно выражение `==`: `'' === '0'` (пустая строка из массива и изначальный '0').

Тут уже срабатывает [алгоритм](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) сравнения строк:

> If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then
>
> If Type(x) is String, then return true if x and y are exactly the same sequence of characters (same length and same characters in corresponding positions). Otherwise, return **false**.

То есть строки разные, поэтому `false`.

---

Я просто читал [эту страницу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47015361/why-is-0-false), там залайкан не правильный ответ.

Comment: с чего решили, что там не правильный ответ? Суть та же, не пустая строка '0' и пустая строка '' (от преобразования массива) не равны

Comment: @ThisMan "JavaScript cannot coerce them to the same type" По алгоритму что я написал, он привод к одинаковому типу: `'' === '0'`. Еще "and one is falsy the other is not.", это не понятно, там пример кода внизу где оба Truthy. Еще такой прикол: "if you coerce an empty array to a number, you get it's length - which is zero", путает новичков.

Comment: Я так понял типы преобразовываются именно так? Я не ошибся не в чем?

Comment: ошибся. _ToPrimitive вызывается с hint String_ - на самом деле он вызывает **без** hint, об этом говорит вызов `ToPrimitive(x)`, `hint` передавался бы отдельным параметром, например `ToPrimitive(x, 'number')` или `ToPrimitive(x, 'string')`

Comment: Описание работы `ToPrimitive` есть в ответе на вопрос [В чем разница между valueOf и toString](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/544918/186999)

Comment: @Grundy то есть вызывается `ToPrimitive` с `[]` и `hint="default"` (то есть `number`) И получается будет вызыван `toString` из-за условия `Если Type(result) не Object, вернуть result.` И второй вопрос, чтобы я точно был уверен, по сути в примере что я навел с `[] == '0'` будет использовано внутри интерпретатора еще одно сравнение `==` ('' === '0', после приведения массива)? То есть язык может приводить типы и внутри вызывать еще свое сравнение для приведенных типов? (наверно не больше одного сравнения) Надеюсь поняли о чем я))

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько, собственно об этом явно указано в алгоритме из спецификации, если все операнды с типом Object приводятся к примитивным значениям, и далее сравниваются уже примитивы

Comment: @Grundy оказывается `({}) == "[object Object]"` это `true`. `valueOf` получается игнорится из-за того что возвращает сам объект (как и с массивом было).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92234/discussion-between-grundy-and--).