# Почему 0 == [] дает true?

Tags: javascript, массивы, приведение-типов

Мне непонятно почему:

```
console.log(0 == [])
```

показывает true, а:

```
console.log('0' == [])
```

говорит false, что это за мистика?

Comment: чтобы было true, сравнивай `'0' == [0]`

Comment: @Grundy зачем мне так сравнивать? мой вопрос про другое

Comment: Это пример еще одной "мистики".

Comment: @Grundy Почему говоришь что ответ неверный?, я посмотрел ссылку ниже,там написано тоже самое а у человека рядом с фото написано 107к, наверное он знает о чем говорит

Comment: Он может и знает, но говорит ошибочно. И ему на это указывают в комментариях. В любом случае длина никак не проверяется при сравнении. Да и falsy/truthly тоже не имеют отношения в сравнению иначе не выполнялось бы равенство `false == [0]`

Comment: @Grundy чем ты можешь подтвердить что ты прав когда говоришь что он ошибаеться?

Comment: например спецификацией - пример приведен в ответе на дубликат.

Comment: Так же ты сам можешь проверить это, переопределив `toString` у массив и увидев, что он вызывается при сравнении. То есть, при сравнении массив, так как у него нет своего переопределения `ToPrimitive` использует стандартный, что именно происходит в стандартной реализации указано в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/544918/186999)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111585/discussion-between-grundy-and-burg).

Comment: @Grundy Так у тебя ведь тоже самое написано `Если Type(x) - это Object и Type(y) один из следующих: String, Number, или Symbol, вернуть значение выражения ToPrimitive(x) == y.
Вернуть false.` в чем разница то?

Comment: разница в том, как описана работа `ToPrimitive`

Comment: @Grundy этот случай у тебя там не описан, как тогда по твоей версии это будет происходить? Потому что формула что у тебя что в ответе ниже одна и таже, но ниже написано поэтапное обяснение а у тебя в примере нет сравнения с массивом

Comment: Добавил второй дубликат, где описана работа `ToPrimitive`. В случае с массивом у него просто вызовется `toString()`

Comment: @Grundy `пустой массив при попытке привидения к строке (falsy)` так что тогда неверного в этом утверждении?? если я вызову [].toString() я получу '' или falsy

Comment: Разница в том, что во-первых, не используется длина, во-вторых, все отлично приводится к одному типу, в третьих, при сравнении значений одного типа не учитываются `falsy` они или `truthly` - так как это просто обычное сравнение значений одного типа.

Comment: @Grundy как происходит тогода преобразование [] в 0? Если не длинна

Comment: Написал в чате. Ссылка на [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111585/discussion-between-grundy-and-burg) выше в комментариях.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

***В ответе были исправлены ошибки, допущенные при первоначальной публикации.***

---

Все дело в [привидении типов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/Type_coercion).

В случае когда ноль – это строка:

```
console.log("0" == [])
// "0" == ""
// false
```

массив будет приведен к строке, т.е будут сравниваться "0" и "", а поскольку одна строка пустая, а вторая нет, то мы получаем false.

В случае когда 0 – это число, массив так же будет приведен сначала к строке и далее уже эта строка – к 0, поэтому мы получим true:

```
console.log(0 == [])
// 0 == ""
// 0 == 0
// true
```